# How to pass parameter from dagger to Adapter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-databinding

> Provider

```
   @Module
abstract class AddScriptOrContractFragmentProvider {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(AddScriptOrContractFragmentModule::class)])
    abstract fun provideAddScriptOrContractFragmentFactory(): AddScriptOrContractFragment
}
```

> Module

```
 @Module
class AddScriptOrContractFragmentModule {

  @Provides
    fun provideAddScriptOrContractAdapter(context : Context, addScriptOrContractViewModel: AddScriptOrContractViewModel,manageScrip: ManageScrip): AddScriptOrContractAdapter {
        return AddScriptOrContractAdapter(
                ArrayList<AddScrip>(),
                context,
                manageScrip, // ManageScrip is Data class unable to get 
                addScriptOrContractViewModel
        )
    }

}
```

> Adapter

```
    class AddScriptOrContractAdapter(private val mScripResponseList: MutableList<AddScrip>?,
                                 private val context: Context, private val manageScrip: ManageScrip?,
                                 private val viewModel: AddScriptOrContractViewModel) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>() {
}
```

> Fragement

```
mLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    mAddScriptAdapter = AddScriptOrContractAdapter(scripList, context!!, manageScrip,addScriptOrContractViewModel)
    mAddScriptContractBinding.addScriptRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    mAddScriptContractBinding.addScriptRecyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    mAddScriptContractBinding.addScriptRecyclerView.adapter = mAddScriptAdapter
```

> Error Facing

```
error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] view.marketWatch.manage.ManageScrip
 cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
```

What i am trying to do is data binding in adapter with dagger . i want to send a object that is data class to adapter and on that do some business login.
I dont understand what i doing wrong , when i send arraylist() its working fine but when i try to send object or string its facing error please help. Tanx in advance

Comment: How do you create the instance of `ManageScrip`?

Comment: @Inject lateinit var  manageScrip : ManageScrip

Comment: that the issue i don't know how should i provide ? please help me on the same . If you have any example please provide me

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, there are two possible way to provide a dependency:

First one by constructor injection:

```
data class ManageScrip @Inject constructor(val dependency: Dependency)
```

Second by implementing it with an annotated method within a module:

```
@Module
class ProvidingModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideManageScrip(dependency: Dependency) =
            ManageScrip("some", "properties")
}
```

It all depends on your setup and how you actually have to create the `ManageScrip`. In general it would be reasonable for data classes to use the second approach.

Comment: (dependency: Dependency) sorry i don't understand what dependency means over here  
previously i try 

'@Module
class AddScriptOrContractFragmentModule {
@Provides
    fun provideManageScrip(manage : ManageScrip) =
            ManageScrip("some", "properties")
}'

this type but i face cycle error...  basically i want to send a data class from fragment to adapter.. your answer look interesting but i unable to understand ... new in dagger

Comment: That's why I was asking how you create the instance. If you just want to communicate information from one place to another, consider looking into factories. Otherwise you'd have to setup components differently. Anyhow you've not provided enough information about the issue you're facing.